# Python eval equivalent statement in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

In Python using `eval("{'report_name':'sample','duration':'30'}")` statement.

It's generating the output : `{'duration': '30', 'report_name': 'sample'}`

Whether the same kind operation is available in Php? otherwise, can you help me to generate string as I mentioned in output`{'duration': '30', 'report_name': 'sample'}?`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to parse a JSON string? use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in PHP.

Comment: The input string is not valid JSON. [JSON](http://json.org) uses double quotes to enclose the string values.

Comment: The question is ambiguous. PHP also provides an `eval()` function but the example you provided doesn't show how do you want to use it in PHP. The input string you posted is not valid PHP, PHP does not support defining object literals and the [array literals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) use a different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

One way to generate that output, is to just echo it:

```
echo "{'duration': '30', 'report_name': 'sample'}";
```

If you want to convert a PHP array into JSON, it might look like this:

```
$foo = [
   "duration" => "30",
   "report_name" => "sample"
];

echo json_encode($foo);
```

Comment: Hi , I have the string "{'report_name':'sample','duration':'30'}" this format. Need to generate output as {'duration': '30', 'report_name': 'sample'}.Thanks.

Comment: So you're just trying to swap out the order of these properties? That seems... weird.